# Alterar o .NET Frameworks aplicação

Tags: c#, .net

Desenvolvi um app em c# usando o sqlite. Porém ao compilar e instalar em outro computador com o OS XP, deparei com o seguinte erro:

> CreateProcess falhou cod. 193 %1 não é um aplicativo win32 válido

Ao pesquisar no google, pude verificar que o problema estaria no .NET Framework que foi desenvolvido na versão 4.5. Alterei para o 3.0, mas deu conflito ao executar diretamente pelo meu VS 2013, mostrando alguns erros de Linq, etc. ) meu computador é o OS Windows 8.

Existe outra forma de fazer essa alteração para que funcione no XP?

Obrigado

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas acho que não. Se você desenvolveu com o .Net framework 4.5 a aplicação precisa rodar nessa versão ou em uma maior.

Comment: Windows XP é um problema mesmo e será cada vez mais. EU nem acredito que as pessoas tem coragem de usá-lo ainda. Não sei dizer muita coisa, mas vai ter que usar tudo para versões antigas do .Net, talvez tenha que pegar versão antiga da DLL do SQLite, talvez tenha que evitar certos códigos que usam recursos não disponíveis nas versões antigas de todas as DLLs.

Comment: Certo. Porém ao começar a desenvolver a app, não me atentei a esse detalhe e o computador onde será instalado o programa usa o XP. Tentei mudar o .NET Framework, mas deu problema ao executar na minha máquina. Teria algum outro modo sem dar conflitos?

Comment: Desculpe bigown, estava digitando quando você postou sua resposta ; ) É verdade, somente o computador da recepção tem esse XP. Já pedimos para trocar, mas até agora nada.

Comment: O Windows XP já foi até descontinuado. Não sei se vale a pena escrever um sistema pra algo tão antigo.

Answer (score 1):

O Linq foi introduzido na versão 3.5 do .Net! Tente portar sua aplicação para essa versão do framework, que também é compatível com WinXP.